# Map Reduce: Unabale to run the code due to number of errors

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mapreduce

Please have a look at the following code

**Map.java**

```
public class Map extends Mapper<longwritable, intwritable="" text,=""> {
 private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
 private Text word = new Text();

 @Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
   throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String line = value.toString();
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
  while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
   word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
   context.write(word, one);
  }
 }
}
</longwritable,>
```

**Reduce.java**

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<text, intwritable,="" intwritable="" text,=""> {
 @Override
 protected void reduce(
   Text key,
   java.lang.Iterable<intwritable> values,
   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<text, intwritable,="" intwritable="" text,="">.Context context)
   throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable value : values) {
   sum += value.get();
  }
  context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
 }
}
</text,></intwritable></text,>
```

**WordCount.java**

```
public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          Configuration conf = new Configuration();

          Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
          job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

          job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
          job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

          job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
          job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

          job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
          job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

          job.waitForCompletion(true);
        }

}
```

This entire code is extracted from [this](http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-run-elastic-mapreduce-job) `Map Reduce` tutorial (http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-run-elastic-mapreduce-job)

. As soon as I copied these classes into Eclipse, it showed lot of errors like Cannot be `Resolved By Type`. It is reasonable because the classes this code is using as instances are no where to find in default JDK, and the tutorial has not given any instructions to download any Library. I ignored it thinking it has something to do with `Elastic Map Reduce` in server side.

As soon as I uploaded this to Amazon Elastic Map Reduce, created a job flow and run the program, it gave me following errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Configuration cannot be resolved to a type
    Configuration cannot be resolved to a type
    Job cannot be resolved to a type
    Job cannot be resolved to a type
    Text cannot be resolved to a type
    IntWritable cannot be resolved to a type
    TextInputFormat cannot be resolved to a type
    TextOutputFormat cannot be resolved to a type
    FileInputFormat cannot be resolved
    Path cannot be resolved to a type
    FileOutputFormat cannot be resolved
    Path cannot be resolved to a type

    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

How can I make this code work? Do I have to download any library for that? How can I make this code run and see the results? This is my very first Experience in Amazon and Elastic Map reduce, and yes, first experience with Big Data as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you mean ,you didn`t add any hadoop jar to your project, and you ignored the compilation error, and hoped this can run in the server side which installed a hadoop-client?

If it is true, that is impossiable.

You must add the hadoop-client.XX.jar to your project ,any version is OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where is this Jar? I only copied that code and ran it

Comment: You can download the hadoop-client.xxx.jar from http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads.html , choose a version you want to add .  Also the apach-hadoop is as blow: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html                                                But, if you want to run your task in the Amazon server, you have to make suer the version of hadoop you choose is the same to the Amazon server. I don`t know which version Amazon used, maybe they open an api or documentation stuff for it ,you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Add all hadoop jars to the project in eclipse and if your code has no errors then you may export it as a jar and run the jar in hadoop.

To add jars goto "Build Path", choose "Configure Build Path" and "Add external jars". (Choose all hadoop jars and add them)

Answer (score 0):

To people encountering this error:

You can right-click on the project you created.

Build path->Configure build path > Add external jar files inside the libraries tab.

Hadoop Jar is located inside file system>usr>lib
you can,

Browse thru :  file syster>usr>lib>hadoop> add all the jar files starting from **hadoop-annotations.jar** till the last jar **[parquet-tools.jar]**

Then again add new external jars and this time add all jars present in the client folder ;

path(file syster>usr>lib>hadoop>client)